# How to specify user & group of volume via docker-compose?

Tags: linux, docker

I am launching a docker environment by means of docker-compose. This provisions both a mysql and nginx process. The latter mounts a path that contains the folder that will be served.

The issue is that while nginx runs as the user 'nginx', the volume gets mounted as xfs:xfs. This causes an issue since there is a php script that needs to be able to write to disk.

On the host OS (Linux running in Vagrant, for dev purposes), the folder is owner is www-data:www-data.

I can't work out how to have the volume mounted with the appropriate user.

My environment gets loaded as follows:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

and the nginx image part of the docker-compose-dev.yml file is:

```
webserver:
  container_name: somedomain_website
  image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest
  working_dir: /application
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: webdev.somedomain.com
    LETSENCRYPT_HOST: somedomain.com
    LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: xyz@somedomain.com
#    PGID: 33
#    PUID: 33
  volumes:
    - ../www/2019:/var/www/html/2019
    - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx_dev.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
    - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx_dev.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
    - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

BTW I did try specifying `PGID` and `PUID`, but that breaks nginx:

```
2019-02-11 05:35:38,584 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status 78; not expected)
2019-02-11 05:35:41,595 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 25
[11-Feb-2019 05:35:41] ERROR: [pool www] cannot get uid for user 'nginx'
[11-Feb-2019 05:35:41] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2019-02-11 05:35:41,635 INFO exited: php-fpm (exit status
```

Can anyone suggest how to deal with this issue?

Using docker-compose 1.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.